# Magento Banners between products?

Tags: magento, ads, banner

I have a [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) shop and I want to place a banner after every 4 products. How can I do this? I have tried finding an extension for this, but I did not find the correct one.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have grid mode go into

```
catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Credits to @Jeveni Smirnov for explaining

then find :

```
 <?php // Grid Mode ?>
```

Then after the `</li>`

Put in this

```
<?php if($i % 3 == 0){ ?>
<div id="banner">
-- Banner here --
</div>           
<?php } ?>
```

Then after every 3rd product the banner will show.

The style i used for the banner

```
#banner{
    width:100% ; 
    height: 70px; 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    background: #fff; 
    font-size: 24px; 
    color: #f8a26f;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Category products are displayed from:

```
catalog/product/list.phtml
```

file. There is such variable as

```
$_iterator
```

With help of these 2 facts you are able to solve your task. ;)

P.S. If you need more help, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

For RWD Theme:

Find the Grid section.

Under:

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
```

Insert:

```
<?php

$counter = 0;
$position = rand(1, $_collectionSize);

?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

<?php if ($counter == $position): ?>
    <li>banana</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Under:

```
</li>
```

Insert:

```
<?php $counter++; ?>
```

This script randomizes where the banner will show based on:

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = 3; ?>
```

Comment: While this is a nice approach it messes up decorateList resulting in empty spaces in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to note, if you are using Enterprise Edition then trying to achieve this with banners/widgets is not possible because you can not place a widget inside the products layout on a category page. Going the list.phtml and $_iterator route is the only way to achieve this (as per the other comment)

Answer (score 0):

It could be pointed out the the actual banner content could and probably should be created in a static block and that block be used to load the banner into the code ideas already suggested here.